# Can I set a CMake variable to the result of a boolean expression?

Tags: variables, cmake

Consider the following CMake code:

```
if(VAR_1 STREQUAL VAR_2)
    set(VAR_3 ON)
else()
    set(VAR_3 OFF)
endif()
```

I want to write the same thing, but as a one-liner. I don't particularly care which boolean representation `VAR_3` ends up using. So what I need is to set it to the result of the evaluation of a boolean expression.

Now, this doesn't work:

```
set(VAR_3 (VAR_1 STREQUAL VAR_2) )
```

nor does this:

```
set(VAR_3 (${VAR_1} STREQUAL ${VAR_2}) )
```

Rather, they get me something like `;ValueOfVar1Here;STREQUAL;ValueOfVar2Here;` - which isn't what I want.

Can I get the evaluation I want somehow?

Answer (score 6):

No you can't. There is one cmake command on one line only. Each cmake script command invokation has to end with a `)` (followed optionally by a comment) and followed by a newline (see [cmake doc about source files](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-language.7.html#source-files)). You can still write a macro that does what you want.

```
macro(assign_me_bool var)
     if(${ARGN})
         set(${var} ON)
     else()
         set(${var} OFF)
     endif()
endmacro()

assign_me_bool(VAR_3 VAR_1 STREQUAL VAR_2)
```

Comment: This is a nice workaround, but - is there a similar such macro that's available with CMake itself? e.g. in some module?